# ColdFusion form not submitting data to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I'm having some trouble with my ColdFusion code,
I have a simple form, and all I want it to do is to add the values to the database. I keep getting the error:
"error code 206
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Operand type clash: int is incompatible with text"

Here's my code:

```
    <div class="form">
    <form method="post" name="color">
        ID:
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
        Color Name:
        <input type="text" name="color" id="color">
        Hex Value:
        <input type="text" name="hex" id="hex">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <cfif structKeyExists(form, "color")>
        <cfquery datasource="bentest" name="insertColor">
            USE [benTest]

            INSERT INTO color_codes
            (id ,color, hexvalue)
            VALUES
            (#form.id#, '#form.color#', #form.hex#)
        </cfquery>
        <p>You've added a color to the database!</p>
    </cfif>
</div>
```

And if I remove the single quotes from #form.color#, I get "Invalid column name '(what I entered)'."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the hexvalue field in the database is a text field, e.g. nvarchar, varchar, text, then at a minimum you will need quotes around the variable... i.e.

```
<cfquery datasource="bentest" name="insertColor">
    USE [benTest]

    INSERT INTO color_codes (id ,color, hexvalue)
    VALUES (#form.id#, '#form.color#', '#form.hex#')
</cfquery>
```

However I strongly suggest you also cfqueryparam them too, i.e.

```
<cfquery datasource="bentest" name="insertColor">
    USE [benTest]

    insert into 
       [color_codes] (
          [Id], 
          [Color], 
          [HexValue]
    )
    values (
        <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Id#" cfquerytype="cf_sql_integer">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Color#" cfquerytype="cf_sql_varchar">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Hex#" cfquerytype="cf_sql_varchar">
    )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Definitely use cfqueryparam on ALL variable query parameters. Then you do not need to worry about data type casting or what values should or should not be quoted. Also it is especially important with databases like SQL Server because they support the execution of multiple statements out the box ie are vulnerable to sql injection. Using cfqueryparam means you are using [bind variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bind_variable) which come with all kinds of great benefits, one of most important being sql injection protection.

Comment: Thank you! a few other people have mentioned cfqueryparam, but I wasn't sure quite how to use it. This makes sense to me! Thank you!

Comment: I replaced them with cfqueryparam and it works perfectly, thanks @Jedihomer Townend & @Leigh!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes for `#form.hex#` because it is a string value, not integer:

```
INSERT INTO color_codes
        (id ,color, hexvalue)
        VALUES
        (#form.id#, '#form.color#', '#form.hex#')
```

Actually, it looks like your id is a text field as well. Is this how it is set up in the database? You're not doing any verification that the value is numeric.... Often the ID is an auto-incrementing field, and not supplied by the user at all on insert.

Comment: *You need to add quotes* ... Though what you really should be using is cfqueryparam ;-) which avoids the need for quotes, can boost performance and more importantly helps protect against sql injection (your current query is vulnerable).